# Storing Paragraph

Tags: php, mysql, blogs, paragraphs

How would I store posts in my forum website into MySQL, in such a way that when I call then back to the site, they retain formatting such as paragraphs, numbering etc.? Just like the way post are displayed on this very site or other forum websites.

Or is there an alternative that would not necessarily require data base storage?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're having trouble with. A database would be perfect for this. You'll likely find most of the code you need already written in examples and documentation. You can store HTML in the database.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp - The length of each data type. Decide how big you need it to be.

Comment: Look at WYSIWYG for how to retain the formatting... or you could use a CMS that is already written to do this.

Comment: I appreciate your comments above.i am building a php mysql forum website where people can post questions and people can provide answers.however,when someone posts more than one paragraph say three paragraph,the site displays that content as one paragraph.I am looking for a way in which I can retain the paragraphs when I query the DB.Thanks.